# Key binding for § symbol in Emacs

Tags: emacs, unicode, keystroke

I'm working in Ubuntu, but since the standard way of inserting unicode characters (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and, after that, the unicode code) doesn't work inside emacs, I've, in my `.emacs`, some keystrokes for different unicode symbols which I use frequently, for example:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c b") "☛")
```

and every symbol works fine, except the symbol §, which is replaced by a simple dash ("-") when I use the corresponding keystroke:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c y") "§")
```

The question is, what does it make this symbol different for other symbols and how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`global-set-key` usually expects a function, so this should work:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c y") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "§")))
```

But you're better off using the excellent `insert-char` function:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f2> u") 'insert-char)
```

It understands hex Unicode as well as text description (with completion and all).
Just press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to see the completions.

Answer (score 2):

You can insert unicode chars in emacs by doing <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>`<unicode-hex>`<kbd>RET</kbd>. So to insert `§` do <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>00A7<kbd>RET</kbd>.

You can bind `insert-char` (the command run by <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>) to a simpler key if you wish, or define a custom function and bind it to a key as follows

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c y") (lambda () (interactive) (insert "§")))
```

Comment: Yes I know, but this approach is too "irritating" when I need to write this symbol frequently.

Answer (score 1):

A *general solution* to the need to insert a number of Unicode chars quickly is to define a *command for each*, dedicated to inserting it, and bind that command to a simple key sequence.

That is, in effect, what @abo-abo and @Iqbal have offered you, in the form of:

```
(lambda () (interactive) (insert "§")))
```

If you have *multiple* such chars that you want to create such commands for, then 
library [**`ucs-cmds.el`**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/ucs-cmds.el) can help -- in two ways:

- It  provides a **macro**, `ucsc-make-commands`, that lets you, in one fell swoop, define commands for whole ranges of Unicode chars.  For example:

  - `(ucsc-make-commands "^cjk")` defines an insert-char command for *each* Chinese, Japanese, and Korean Unicode character.
  - `(ucsc-make-commands "^greek [a-z]+ letter")` does the same for *each* Greek letter.
  - `(ucsc-make-commands "arabic")` does the same for *each* Arabic character.
- It provides a replacement **command** (`ucsc-insert`) for `C-x 8 RET`, which acts exactly the same as the vanilla command (`insert-char`), except that if you give it a negative prefix argument then it not only inserts the char you choose but it also *creates an insertion command* for it (i.e., the kind of command that the macro creates in bulk).

The names of the commands created by macro `ucsc-make-commands` and command `ucsc-insert` are exactly the same as the Unicode names of the chars themselves, except that they are lowercase and have hyphens (`-`) in place of space chars.